# Help in understanding definition of algebraic topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces, simplicial-complex

I am having trouble understanding the following from Robert Ghrist's book "Elementary Applied Topology" related to simplicial complexes, but first two definitions:

> A family $ \Delta $ of non-empty finite subsets of a set S is an abstract simplicial complex if, for every set X in Δ, and every non-empty subset Y $\subset$ X, Y also belongs to $ \Delta $.
>
> The standard n-simplex in $ \mathbb{R}^{n+1} $ is the following set:
> $ \Delta ^{n} = \{ (t_0,...,t_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} | \sum_{i=0}^{n} t_i = 1 \space \space \space \forall i: t_i \geq 0 \} $

Here is what I don't understand from Ghrist's book, from page 27:
[image]

How exactly are the faces of the standard simplex defined? which coordinates are nullified in the definition? I don't exactly understand coordinate subspace restrictions.
I also don't understand the defintion of the skeleton given, how can they look at the disjoint union of standard simplices which seem to be the same, also I don't understand the exact definition of the equivalence relation ~ given below and why exactly we have nesting $ X^{(k)} \supset X^{(k-1)} $? I guess what really would help me understand this matter is a representative example of a skeleton and geometric realization of a specific abstract simplicial complex,  would someone please help me, I thank all helpers.

Comment: For the concept of disjoint union see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union

Comment: For specific examples, you have exhibited one such example in your own question, as reproduced from Ghrist's book. Look up other examples in other algebraic topology books such as the one by Hatcher.

Answer (score 2):

Faces: For a $k$-simplex, a $k$ face is the whole simplex. The $k-1$ faces are those with one of the coordinates set to $0$. So for a 2-simplex, defined by $x+y+z = 1$, there are three 1-faces: $x+y = 1$ and $z = 0$; $x+z = 1$ and $y = 0$; and $y+z = 1$ and $x = 0$.

In general, the $k-p$ faces of a $k$-simplex are those in which exactly $p$  of the coordinates are set to 0. That means that there are $k \choose p$ of them.

For the further questions, just saying "I don't understand" isn't really enough for me to know WHAT you don't understand, so I cannot help there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I mostly need a clarifying example to help me with this, would you please help in providing one?

Comment: I agree with Lee Mosher's comments above: there are lots of topology books (like Hatcher's) that address this, and my copying one into an answer isn't a good use of my time or yours, since I'll probably make typos. But I also think that Ghrist has made things more complicated than necessary, at least at the start. For a FINITE simplicial complex, the geometric realization is straightforward: you label the vertices $1\ldots p$, and associate to $v_p$ the point $e_p \in \mathbb R^\infty$ that's all zeroes except a $1$ in the $p$th place. A simplex containing ${v_1, v_3, v_4}$ is then identified

Comment: ...with the convex hull of $e_1, e_3, e_4$, and so on (for simplicies of any dimension). This shows that every finite simplicial complex admits an embedding into $\mathbb R^\infty$ (which is more or less the start of Whitney's proof of the embedding theorem, I think...but it's been a long time since I looked at that). This construction is much simpler than mapping each $k$-simplex of your complex into a standard $k$-simplex in a copy of $\mathbb R^\infty$ and then taking a quotient...but it happens not to extend well to the case where there are uncountably many simplices, while the other does.